# How to get information from text and safe it in variable with python

Tags: python-3.x, text, text-processing

So I am trying to make an offline dictionary and as a source for the words, I am using a .txt file. I have some questions related to that. How can I find a specific word in my text file and save it in a variable? Also does the length of my file matter and will it affect the speed? That's just a part of my .txt file:

Abendhimmel m вечерно небе.|-|
Abendkasse  f Theat вечерна каса.|-|
Abendkleid  n вечерна рокля.|-|
Abendland   n o.Pl. geh Западът.|-|

The thing that I want is to save the wort, for example, Abendkasse and everything else till this symbol |-| in one variable. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to look at python's standard library functions (on open files) called realines() and read(). I don't know how large your file is, but you can usually just read the entire thing into ram (with read or readlines) and then search through the string you then get. Searchin can be done with regex or just with a simple loop.

The length of your file will sort of matter, in that opening larger files will take slightly longer. Though usually this is still pretty fast, even for large textfiles. In fact, I think in many cases it will be faster to first read the entire file, because once it is read into ram, all operations on it will be way faster.

an example:

```py
with open("yourlargetextfile.txt", f):
    contents = f.readlines()
    for line in contents:
        # split every line into parts from |-| to the next |-|
        parts = line.split("|-|")
```

Comment: And what should be the regex pattern for this: -Abendkasse f Theat вечерна каса.|-|, where I want to get the information between "-" and "|-|"?Also, what do you mean with a loop?